# Custom button in android & giving custom border color

Tags: android

I am Trying to get a clickable effect for a `white button` that shows clickable effect on clicking it

My button

What i have tried is

I have achieved clickable effect for the button using a selector as below

black_button_for_account.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#343434" />

            <stroke 
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:color="#171717" />

            <corners android:radius="3dp" />

            <padding 
                android:bottom="10dp" 
                android:left="10dp" 
                android:right="10dp" 
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
     </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient 
                android:angle="270" 
                android:endColor="#FFFFFF" 
                android:startColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <stroke 
                android:width="1dp" 
                android:color="#FFFFFF" />

            <corners android:radius="4dp" />

            <padding 
                android:bottom="10dp" 
                android:left="10dp" 
                android:right="10dp" 
                android:top="10dp" />
        </shape>
     </item>

</selector>
```

How to give a border of like `3dp` size for the button retaining the above effect color for the border like be `black`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the following

```
<stroke 
  android:width="3dp" 
   android:color="#000" />
```

Comment: change it on both places.